# How to implement slider menu in react Native

Tags: ios, facebook, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react.
I need to develop slider menu in React-native.
I follow below link but that is not I want 
http://www.reactnative.com/a-slide-menu-inspired-from-android-for-react-native/

Actually I need image which I attached here.

[image]

Please help me..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This react native package is pretty extensive, and really nice to use:

https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer

This is just a snippet of my code, you could create a menu bar with a button that calls the openDrawer method, and using this drawer you can set the animation to be however you like, and include a scrollview inside the drawer itself. Hope this helps!

```
var React = require('react-native');
var {
  StyleSheet,
  Component,
  View,
  Text,
  Navigator,
  TouchableHighlight,
  TouchableOpacity,
} = React;

var styles = require('./styles');
var Drawer = require('react-native-drawer')

var drawerStyles = {
  drawer: {
    shadowColor: "#000000",
    shadowOpacity: 0.8,
    shadowRadius: 0,
  }
}

var MainPage = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      drawerType: 'overlay',
      openDrawerOffset:.3,
      closedDrawerOffset:0,
      panOpenMask: .1,
      panCloseMask: .9,
      relativeDrag: false,
      panStartCompensation: true,
      openDrawerThreshold: .25,
      tweenHandlerOn: false,
      tweenDuration: 550,
      tweenEasing: 'easeInOutQuad',
      disabled: false,
      tweenHandlerPreset: null,
      acceptDoubleTap: true,
      acceptTap: true,
      acceptPan: true,
      rightSide: false,
      showView: true,
    }
  },

  setDrawerType: function(type){
    this.setState({
      drawerType: type
    });
  },

  openDrawer: function(){
    this.refs.drawer.open();
  },

  closeDrawer: function(){
    this.refs.drawer.close();
  },

  setStateFrag: function(frag){
    this.setState(frag);
  },


    render: function() {

    var menu = <Menu 
                  closeDrawer={this.closeDrawer}
                  navigator={this.props.navigator}  />;


    return (
      <Drawer
        ref="drawer"
        onClose={this.onClose}
        type={this.state.drawerType}
        animation={this.state.animation}
        openDrawerOffset={this.state.openDrawerOffset}
        closedDrawerOffset={this.state.closedDrawerOffset}
        panOpenMask={this.state.panOpenMask}
        panCloseMask={this.state.panCloseMask}
        relativeDrag={this.state.relativeDrag}
        panStartCompensation={this.state.panStartCompensation}
        openDrawerThreshold={this.state.openDrawerThreshold}
        content={**YOURCUSTOMENU**}
        styles={drawerStyles}
        disabled={this.state.disabled}
        tweenHandler={this.tweenHandler}
        tweenDuration={this.state.tweenDuration}
        tweenEasing={this.state.tweenEasing}
        acceptDoubleTap={this.state.acceptDoubleTap}
        acceptTap={this.state.acceptTap}
        acceptPan={this.state.acceptPan}
        changeVal={this.state.changeVal}
        negotiatePan={false}
        side={this.state.rightSide ? 'right' : 'left'}
        >
        <View>
          <**YOURTOOLBAR** onPress={this.openDrawer}/> 
          <**YOURCONTENT_VIEW**/>
        </View>
      </Drawer>

    );
  },



});



module.exports = MainPage;
```

Comment: npm i --save react-native-navigation-drawer           after i  install drawer I give the "invalide directory /User/node_module/react-native-navigation-drawer"

Comment: you should be running npm install react-native-drawer --save (take out the word "navigation", this is a differnet module). Make sure you run it from within your RN project's root folder.

Comment: I need function like this  http://www.incredibleandros.com/slidingpanel-android-example/ in IOS

Comment: and here 'CustomeMenu, Toolbar, ContentView how to implement those

Comment: To do that, you need to implement a drawer/menu, and pass that into the Drawer component's "content" prop (labeled as YOURCUSTOMMENU). For that, a simple scrollview should be fine.

then, the child of the Drawer should contain any content you want to go under the drawer. Inside the child of the Drawer, you can have a toolbar (androidToolbar, or a custom toolbar of your own choice). Good luck!

Comment: Custom Menu should essentially just be a scrollview, toolbar is just a view that takes up some portion on the top of the screen (or you can look into androidToolbar), and contentview is just whatever content you want to be on the screen itself.

Comment: Yes it's work thanks.Now i want to add top button.anyway thanks.

Comment: Your welcome! For the button, you should be using TouchHighlight, and as for the view you can use [vector icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons)

Comment: and another thing when mask coming to screen, screen have to move left to right .is it possible with this method.

Comment: if you set side in 
`side={this.state.rightSide ? 'right' : 'left'}"`
to 'left', it'll move left to right.

Comment: no Need to move content  <**YOURCONTENT_VIEW**/> left to right when   slide come to screen

Comment: I Need to move content <**YOURCONTENT_VIEW**/> left to right when slide come to screen

Comment: Here's an example if your need a left and right drawer using react-native-drawer: https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer/issues/219

Answer (score 7):

I've added [an example](https://github.com/efkan/rndrawer-implemented-rnrouter) that [implements react-native-router-flux](https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux) component to [react-native-drawer](https://github.com/root-two/react-native-drawer). In this way it presents an easy scaffolding as cross-platform.

[image]

Comment: For anyone who arrives later, this sample is deprecated: "Deprecated - This repo uses obsolete versions of react-native-router-flux and react-native-drawer."

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you want to toogle the slider menu with the `hamburger button`.

Although [react-native-navigation-drawer](https://github.com/ilansas/react-native-navigation-drawer/)

That can be achieved with the [`toogleSlideMenu`](https://github.com/ilansas/react-native-navigation-drawer/blob/master/index.js#L113) function of the `SliderMenu`.

A simple example might be:

```
import React, {
  View,
  Text,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';

import SlideMenu from 'react-native-navigation-drawer';


var BasicExample = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View>
          <Text onPress={() => this._slideMenu.toogleSlideMenu()}> Your status bar </Text>
        </View>
        <SlideMenu
          ref={(c) => this._slideMenu = c}
          menu={<Menu />} 
          >
          <View>
            <Text>Your content</Text>
          </View>
        </SlideMenu>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var Menu = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView
          contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
          style={styles.scrollView}>
          <Text>Gallery</Text>
          <Text>Latest</Text>
          <Text>Events</Text>
          <Text>Update</Text>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. when i going to try this.it says.invalide directory /User/node_module/react-native-navigation-drawer. I installed react-native-navigation-drawer.but that message give to me..

Answer (score 0):

You can check this complete sidemenu project on github. This project contains ToolbarAndroid, routes, DrawerLayoutAndroid, overflow menu and other components.

https://github.com/darde/react-native-sidemenu